# SCSS/Compass modules not working?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, codekit

I've exported a CodePen project (specifically [this one](http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/pvwZJp/)) to use as a learning reference for my exploration into SCSS.

I'm using CodeKit to compile my SCSS, but when I make any changes to the sass file, and so overwriting the existing CSS from the download, I lose functionality, it seems because the compiler is not compiling for cross-browser support (should this be via the css3 module?) – so for example where it had compiled to "transform, -webkit-transform, -moz-transform, etc", now it only outputs plain old "transform".

The `@import "compass/css3"` line is at the head of the scss file.

I get no errors from CodeKit. I have tried 'compass watch' from the command line with a direct manual install of Compass, but no joy with that either.

So, what gives? I feel like maybe I should be doing something like installing these modules first before importing them, but I really can't see an obvious solution.

Comment: You do realize that your codepen is configured to use Autoprefixer, right?

Comment: I didn't even know that was a thing. But yes, you're absolutely right, that was what was missing. Thank you. Incidentally, isn't that what the css3 module is supposed to do anyway though? Or would one have to extend it with a specific mixin (if Autoprefixer didn't already have it covered)?